# Can we use CloudantSync(CDTDatastore) encryption with IMFData SDK?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

Now CloudantSync(CDTDataStore) can encrypt localstore using [CloudantSyncEncryption](https://github.com/cloudant/CDTDatastore/blob/master/doc/encryption.md).
[IMFData of MobileFirst Platform Foundation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/cloud/data/t_data_cloudantsec.html?locale=en) adds security and depends on CloudantSync.

Is there any way combination of IMFData and CloudantSync Encryption?

IMFData creates local data store like below.

```
IMFDataManager *manager = [IMFDataManager sharedInstance];
NSString *name = @"automobiledb";
NSError *error = nil;

//Create local store
CDTStore *store = [manager localStore:name error:&error];
```

CloudantSync creates encrypted local data store like below.

```
// To create an encrypted datastore, create your datastore using an object
// implementing the CDTKeyProvider protocol
CDTDatastoreManager *manager =[[CDTDatastoreManager alloc] initWithDirectory:path error:&error];
CDTEncryptionKeychainProvider *provider = [CDTEncryptionKeychainProvider 
                                           providerWithPassword:@"blahblah" 
                                           forIdentifier:@"default"];
CDTDatastore *encrypted = [manager datastoreNamed:@"encrypted_datastore"
                        withEncryptionKeyProvider:provider
                                            error:&error];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this yet, but work to support it is in progress. Keep an eye on new releases.

*Update*: IMFData 1.1.1 provide support for using encryption. See [the docs here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/IMFData/1.1.1/Classes/IMFDataManager.html#task_EncryptionKey%20Methods) for info on creating encrypted local datastores.